# Sudden reinitialization of train and validation loss and slow covergence while training CNN in Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I am a beginner in deep learning, especially in designing neural networks from scratch and I am trying to build a B/W image colorizer using the Autoencoder concept in Pytorch while referring this Keras architecture from [here](https://blog.floydhub.com/colorizing-b-w-photos-with-neural-networks/) using the dataset [here](https://www.floydhub.com/emilwallner/datasets/colornet/2/images). The Keras architecture for reference:

```
#Design the neural network
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(256, 256, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

# Finish model
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')

# Image transformer
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    rotation_range=20,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# Generate training data
batch_size = 50

def image_a_b_gen(batch_size):
    for batch in datagen.flow(Xtrain, batch_size=batch_size):
        lab_batch = rgb2lab(batch)
        X_batch = lab_batch[:,:,:,0]
        Y_batch = lab_batch[:,:,:,1:] / 128
        yield (X_batch.reshape(X_batch.shape+(1,)), Y_batch)

# Train model
TensorBoard(log_dir='/output')
model.fit_generator(image_a_b_gen(batch_size), steps_per_epoch=10000, epochs=1)
```

And this is the architecture that I have built in PyTorch:

```
class AutoEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.model = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(1, 64, (3,3), padding = (1,1)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(64, 128, (3,3), padding = (1,1), stride = (2,2)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(128, 128, (3,3), padding = (1,1)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(128, 256, (3,3), padding = (1,1), stride = (2,2)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(256, 256, (3,3), padding = (1,1)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(256, 512, (3,3), padding = (1,1), stride = (2,2)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, (3,3), padding = (1,1)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(512, 256, (3,3), padding = (1,1)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(256, 128, (3,3), padding = (1,1)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Upsample(scale_factor= (2,2)),
        nn.Conv2d(128, 64, (3,3), padding = (1,1)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Upsample(scale_factor= (2,2)),
        nn.Conv2d(64, 32, (3,3), padding = (1,1)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(32, 2, (3,3), padding = (1,1)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Upsample(scale_factor= (2,2)),       
)

  def forward(self, input):
       output = self.model(input)
       return output
```

And initialize like this:

```
model = AutoEncoder()
loss_func = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

This is the training function (trained on Google Colab) with validation incorporated:

```
  def train(model, optimizer, loss_func, train_loader, val_loader, epochs, device = 'cuda'):
  model = model.to(device)
  loss_func = loss_func.to(device)
  training_loss = 0
  valid_loss = 0
  save_path = {'grayscale': '/content/outputs/gray/', 'colorized': '/content/outputs/color/',
               'target': '/content/outputs/target/'}

  for epoch in range(e+1, e+1+epochs):
    print('Starting epoch {}'.format(epoch))
    epoch_start = time.time()
    training_loss = 0.0
    valid_loss = 0.0

    model.train()
    b = 1
    for batch in train_loader:
      batch_start = time.time()
      optimizer.zero_grad()
      img_gray, img_ab, og_image = batch
      input, target = img_gray, img_ab
      input, target = input.to(device), target.to(device)
      output = model(input)
      loss = loss_func(output, target)
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()

      training_loss += loss.data.item()
      if b % 20 == 0:
        print('Epoch: {} , Batch: {} Training Loss: {:.4f}, Time: {:.2f}'.format(
        epoch, b, loss.data.item(), time.time() - batch_start))
      b += 1

    training_loss /= len(train_loader)

    model.eval()
    b = 1
    for batch in val_loader:
      batch_start = time.time()
      img_gray, img_ab, og_image = batch
      input, target = img_gray, img_ab
      input, target = input.to(device), target.to(device)
      output = model(input)
      loss = loss_func(output, target)

      valid_loss += loss.data.item()

      j = random.randint(1,9)
      save_name = 'epoch-{}batch-{}img-{}.jpg'.format(epoch, b, j)
      save_image(input[j].detach().cpu(), output[j].detach().cpu(), target[j].detach().cpu(),
                 og_image[j].detach().cpu(), save_path=save_path, save_name=save_name)
        
      print('Epoch: {} , Batch: {} Valid Loss: {:.4f}, Time: {:.2f}'.format(
      epoch, b, loss.data.item(), time.time() - batch_start))

      b += 1

    valid_loss /= len(val_loader)

    # model saving code here
  
    print('Epoch: {} , Training Loss: {:.4f}, Validation Loss: {:.4f}, Time: {:.2f}'
    .format(epoch, training_loss, valid_loss, time.time() - epoch_start))
```

However, on training this model, I found that the convergence speed was slower than I expected and also the training and validation loss shoots up suddenly (reinitializes to loss that was there at epoch 1) at a certain epoch (epoch 40) as seen in the logs below and then increases. I cannot ascertain the reason for this happening even though I did search the net for it. I did overfit the model on a single image to check if the model is able to learn images, and it gives great results after about 200 epochs on that single image.

Any other suggestions to improve training speed are also welcome.

The logs:

```
Starting epoch 35
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 20 Training Loss: 106.5381, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 40 Training Loss: 164.4004, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 60 Training Loss: 187.2683, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 80 Training Loss: 125.9881, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 100 Training Loss: 178.2198, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 120 Training Loss: 145.3067, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 140 Training Loss: 172.2734, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 160 Training Loss: 161.0511, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 180 Training Loss: 154.7270, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 200 Training Loss: 105.7089, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 220 Training Loss: 136.7364, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 240 Training Loss: 144.3123, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 1 Valid Loss: 150.3127, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 2 Valid Loss: 136.5788, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 3 Valid Loss: 145.5104, Time: 0.37
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 4 Valid Loss: 174.9318, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 5 Valid Loss: 169.0320, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 6 Valid Loss: 104.9420, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 7 Valid Loss: 139.7437, Time: 0.37
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 8 Valid Loss: 142.1164, Time: 0.37
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 9 Valid Loss: 162.5985, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 10 Valid Loss: 195.1854, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 11 Valid Loss: 134.6287, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 12 Valid Loss: 136.0625, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 13 Valid Loss: 210.8838, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 14 Valid Loss: 171.1289, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 15 Valid Loss: 158.6969, Time: 0.34
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 16 Valid Loss: 245.2010, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 17 Valid Loss: 163.9438, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 18 Valid Loss: 148.4983, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 19 Valid Loss: 153.7577, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 20 Valid Loss: 180.0079, Time: 0.34
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 21 Valid Loss: 123.2093, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 22 Valid Loss: 125.0577, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 23 Valid Loss: 167.9037, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 24 Valid Loss: 142.5038, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 25 Valid Loss: 204.0228, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 26 Valid Loss: 138.4986, Time: 0.31
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 27 Valid Loss: 245.4016, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 28 Valid Loss: 147.9031, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 29 Valid Loss: 86.9302, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 30 Valid Loss: 144.6022, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 31 Valid Loss: 171.0132, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 35 , Batch: 32 Valid Loss: 171.6215, Time: 0.26

Epoch: 35 , Training Loss: 158.2567, Validation Loss: 159.1384, Time: 419.94

Starting epoch 36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 20 Training Loss: 105.9032, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 40 Training Loss: 166.2677, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 60 Training Loss: 187.5138, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 80 Training Loss: 126.4907, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 100 Training Loss: 177.6801, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 120 Training Loss: 145.7679, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 140 Training Loss: 172.1092, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 160 Training Loss: 161.7235, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 180 Training Loss: 154.2764, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 200 Training Loss: 105.0589, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 220 Training Loss: 137.1901, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 240 Training Loss: 143.7092, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 1 Valid Loss: 151.7165, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 2 Valid Loss: 137.6912, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 3 Valid Loss: 148.1911, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 4 Valid Loss: 178.2061, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 5 Valid Loss: 171.2887, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 6 Valid Loss: 105.7988, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 7 Valid Loss: 139.2858, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 8 Valid Loss: 143.3132, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 9 Valid Loss: 164.0428, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 10 Valid Loss: 197.8514, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 11 Valid Loss: 135.2920, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 12 Valid Loss: 136.8798, Time: 0.37
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 13 Valid Loss: 213.7531, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 14 Valid Loss: 173.2047, Time: 0.34
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 15 Valid Loss: 159.9836, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 16 Valid Loss: 250.1139, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 17 Valid Loss: 166.5989, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 18 Valid Loss: 149.8430, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 19 Valid Loss: 156.4111, Time: 0.32
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 20 Valid Loss: 182.4751, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 21 Valid Loss: 125.2163, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 22 Valid Loss: 127.7892, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 23 Valid Loss: 171.6647, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 24 Valid Loss: 145.8683, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 25 Valid Loss: 205.0257, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 26 Valid Loss: 141.0681, Time: 0.32
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 27 Valid Loss: 248.7428, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 28 Valid Loss: 148.8966, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 29 Valid Loss: 88.4646, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 30 Valid Loss: 143.6590, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 31 Valid Loss: 173.3025, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 36 , Batch: 32 Valid Loss: 174.2860, Time: 0.24

Epoch: 36 , Training Loss: 158.3800, Validation Loss: 161.1226, Time: 419.45

Starting epoch 37
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 20 Training Loss: 105.6317, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 40 Training Loss: 165.0392, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 60 Training Loss: 188.5125, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 80 Training Loss: 126.0623, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 100 Training Loss: 177.5551, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 120 Training Loss: 145.3477, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 140 Training Loss: 175.2243, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 160 Training Loss: 160.9049, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 180 Training Loss: 153.3031, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 200 Training Loss: 104.0302, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 220 Training Loss: 135.7108, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 240 Training Loss: 142.8567, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 1 Valid Loss: 150.1673, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 2 Valid Loss: 136.7532, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 3 Valid Loss: 144.9570, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 4 Valid Loss: 173.6571, Time: 0.32
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 5 Valid Loss: 166.9340, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 6 Valid Loss: 104.1471, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 7 Valid Loss: 138.5468, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 8 Valid Loss: 141.9434, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 9 Valid Loss: 163.1604, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 10 Valid Loss: 195.1403, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 11 Valid Loss: 134.0441, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 12 Valid Loss: 135.6687, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 13 Valid Loss: 210.3593, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 14 Valid Loss: 170.5062, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 15 Valid Loss: 157.5619, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 16 Valid Loss: 243.9199, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 17 Valid Loss: 163.0798, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 18 Valid Loss: 147.0687, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 19 Valid Loss: 152.7307, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 20 Valid Loss: 179.4877, Time: 0.34
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 21 Valid Loss: 122.9611, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 22 Valid Loss: 124.0443, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 23 Valid Loss: 165.3088, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 24 Valid Loss: 142.3539, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 25 Valid Loss: 202.2605, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 26 Valid Loss: 137.7361, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 27 Valid Loss: 242.8415, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 28 Valid Loss: 148.3895, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 29 Valid Loss: 86.0574, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 30 Valid Loss: 144.1157, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 31 Valid Loss: 170.8322, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 37 , Batch: 32 Valid Loss: 171.6427, Time: 0.25

Epoch: 37 , Training Loss: 158.1220, Validation Loss: 158.3868, Time: 417.97

Starting epoch 38
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 20 Training Loss: 105.7252, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 40 Training Loss: 163.4334, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 60 Training Loss: 185.7129, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 80 Training Loss: 125.1632, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 100 Training Loss: 178.0677, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 120 Training Loss: 145.0643, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 140 Training Loss: 172.1782, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 160 Training Loss: 160.3347, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 180 Training Loss: 151.9679, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 200 Training Loss: 103.2668, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 220 Training Loss: 134.6251, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 240 Training Loss: 141.8546, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 1 Valid Loss: 150.4089, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 2 Valid Loss: 136.9565, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 3 Valid Loss: 144.5437, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 4 Valid Loss: 172.9728, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 5 Valid Loss: 166.5804, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 6 Valid Loss: 103.4765, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 7 Valid Loss: 138.3381, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 8 Valid Loss: 141.9496, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 9 Valid Loss: 163.2548, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 10 Valid Loss: 194.6338, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 11 Valid Loss: 134.2889, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 12 Valid Loss: 136.0695, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 13 Valid Loss: 209.8143, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 14 Valid Loss: 170.3180, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 15 Valid Loss: 157.3526, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 16 Valid Loss: 243.4948, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 17 Valid Loss: 162.8065, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 18 Valid Loss: 146.0056, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 19 Valid Loss: 152.3638, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 20 Valid Loss: 179.5833, Time: 0.34
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 21 Valid Loss: 122.8715, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 22 Valid Loss: 123.2680, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 23 Valid Loss: 164.3962, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 24 Valid Loss: 142.2115, Time: 0.33
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 25 Valid Loss: 202.0091, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 26 Valid Loss: 137.4782, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 27 Valid Loss: 241.4298, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 28 Valid Loss: 148.7050, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 29 Valid Loss: 86.0582, Time: 0.34
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 30 Valid Loss: 144.0733, Time: 0.33
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 31 Valid Loss: 170.6064, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 38 , Batch: 32 Valid Loss: 171.6329, Time: 0.25

Epoch: 38 , Training Loss: 157.1817, Validation Loss: 158.1235, Time: 418.16

Starting epoch 39
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 20 Training Loss: 105.1230, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 40 Training Loss: 165.4860, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 60 Training Loss: 185.0349, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 80 Training Loss: 124.9884, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 100 Training Loss: 176.9023, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 120 Training Loss: 144.6198, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 140 Training Loss: 170.2020, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 160 Training Loss: 158.3938, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 180 Training Loss: 151.8574, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 200 Training Loss: 103.9747, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 220 Training Loss: 134.2870, Time: 0.67
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 240 Training Loss: 141.7696, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 1 Valid Loss: 151.1508, Time: 0.34
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 2 Valid Loss: 136.8730, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 3 Valid Loss: 145.3472, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 4 Valid Loss: 173.3746, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 5 Valid Loss: 167.3553, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 6 Valid Loss: 103.7990, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 7 Valid Loss: 139.3748, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 8 Valid Loss: 142.6575, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 9 Valid Loss: 163.5934, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 10 Valid Loss: 194.6525, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 11 Valid Loss: 135.1157, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 12 Valid Loss: 136.4958, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 13 Valid Loss: 209.0710, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 14 Valid Loss: 170.3045, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 15 Valid Loss: 157.5657, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 16 Valid Loss: 243.3302, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 17 Valid Loss: 163.2397, Time: 0.37
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 18 Valid Loss: 146.7547, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 19 Valid Loss: 153.3413, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 20 Valid Loss: 179.2610, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 21 Valid Loss: 123.0379, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 22 Valid Loss: 123.5644, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 23 Valid Loss: 165.4950, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 24 Valid Loss: 142.4183, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 25 Valid Loss: 203.7861, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 26 Valid Loss: 137.3413, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 27 Valid Loss: 241.8771, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 28 Valid Loss: 148.8467, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 29 Valid Loss: 85.9060, Time: 0.34
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 30 Valid Loss: 145.1030, Time: 0.31
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 31 Valid Loss: 171.1640, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 39 , Batch: 32 Valid Loss: 172.1705, Time: 0.26

Epoch: 39 , Training Loss: 156.5736, Validation Loss: 158.5428, Time: 417.88

Starting epoch 40
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 20 Training Loss: 104.7642, Time: 0.68
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 40 Training Loss: 199.1840, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 60 Training Loss: 203.7560, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 80 Training Loss: 164.9527, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 100 Training Loss: 186.1097, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 120 Training Loss: 155.4772, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 140 Training Loss: 192.1701, Time: 0.65
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 160 Training Loss: 193.4585, Time: 0.65
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 180 Training Loss: 171.5463, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 200 Training Loss: 117.4412, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 220 Training Loss: 152.0421, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 240 Training Loss: 143.3178, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 1 Valid Loss: 156.7238, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 2 Valid Loss: 147.8145, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 3 Valid Loss: 159.7137, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 4 Valid Loss: 191.3246, Time: 0.32
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 5 Valid Loss: 178.6363, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 6 Valid Loss: 109.2589, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 7 Valid Loss: 144.4912, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 8 Valid Loss: 150.4129, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 9 Valid Loss: 171.8096, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 10 Valid Loss: 210.0710, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 11 Valid Loss: 142.5819, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 12 Valid Loss: 140.7213, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 13 Valid Loss: 221.1351, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 14 Valid Loss: 182.1034, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 15 Valid Loss: 172.3420, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 16 Valid Loss: 264.6909, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 17 Valid Loss: 177.7539, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 18 Valid Loss: 159.2539, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 19 Valid Loss: 167.3184, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 20 Valid Loss: 188.2323, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 21 Valid Loss: 134.6375, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 22 Valid Loss: 137.9939, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 23 Valid Loss: 188.5730, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 24 Valid Loss: 157.5786, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 25 Valid Loss: 215.2611, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 26 Valid Loss: 146.4763, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 27 Valid Loss: 257.7494, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 28 Valid Loss: 156.5165, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 29 Valid Loss: 94.2914, Time: 0.34
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 30 Valid Loss: 146.4372, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 31 Valid Loss: 180.1848, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 40 , Batch: 32 Valid Loss: 178.5307, Time: 0.24

Epoch: 40 , Training Loss: 176.2027, Validation Loss: 169.7069, Time: 414.79

Starting epoch 41
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 20 Training Loss: 128.6025, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 40 Training Loss: 199.1840, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 60 Training Loss: 203.7560, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 80 Training Loss: 164.9526, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 100 Training Loss: 186.1097, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 120 Training Loss: 155.4771, Time: 0.65
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 140 Training Loss: 192.1701, Time: 0.65
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 160 Training Loss: 193.4585, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 180 Training Loss: 171.5462, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 200 Training Loss: 117.4412, Time: 0.64
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 220 Training Loss: 152.0420, Time: 0.65
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 240 Training Loss: 143.3178, Time: 0.65
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 1 Valid Loss: 156.7238, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 2 Valid Loss: 147.8145, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 3 Valid Loss: 159.7137, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 4 Valid Loss: 191.3246, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 5 Valid Loss: 178.6363, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 6 Valid Loss: 109.2589, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 7 Valid Loss: 144.4912, Time: 0.34
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 8 Valid Loss: 150.4129, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 9 Valid Loss: 171.8096, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 10 Valid Loss: 210.0710, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 11 Valid Loss: 142.5818, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 12 Valid Loss: 140.7213, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 13 Valid Loss: 221.1351, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 14 Valid Loss: 182.1034, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 15 Valid Loss: 172.3419, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 16 Valid Loss: 264.6909, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 17 Valid Loss: 177.7538, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 18 Valid Loss: 159.2538, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 19 Valid Loss: 167.3183, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 20 Valid Loss: 188.2322, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 21 Valid Loss: 134.6374, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 22 Valid Loss: 137.9939, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 23 Valid Loss: 188.5730, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 24 Valid Loss: 157.5785, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 25 Valid Loss: 215.2611, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 26 Valid Loss: 146.4763, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 27 Valid Loss: 257.7494, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 28 Valid Loss: 156.5165, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 29 Valid Loss: 94.2914, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 30 Valid Loss: 146.4371, Time: 0.35
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 31 Valid Loss: 180.1848, Time: 0.36
Epoch: 41 , Batch: 32 Valid Loss: 178.5307, Time: 0.26
Epoch: 41 , Training Loss: 178.2872, Validation Loss: 169.7068, Time: 414.65
```

Comment: Slower than expected - What do you expect and why do you expect it? Shooting up suddenly - can be a bad data point or a too high learning rate.

Comment: The Keras model from the linked site is faster in convergence. Okay, so there is nothing wrong with the model architecture or the training loop? I was afraid that might be the case even though I tested it on a single image